An old movie about a scientist who developed a gadget to hold the soul
I watched it in the cinema between 1967 to 1975. 
Opening scene is current day head on collision between 2 cars with a man standing in the middle. Surprisingly the man survived. 
Next scene is the explanation of how he survived this head on collision: Rewind 300 years or thereabout. This man was a scientist who happened to see the soul of a person leaving the body before the person is actually dead through a colored filtered lens. Then he devised a gadget to hold the soul with a beam of bright light and lock the soul in a box so that the person will not die forever. 
First he experimented with mice, then himself, then his young daughter. He built a guillotine to pretend to chop off his daughter 's head so as to entice her soul to leave her body. He managed to hold her soul in a beam of light, but the home made guillotine malfunctioned and really beheaded her. At this stage, she's still not dead, but crying. The man and his wife had a big argument, and she switched off the holding beam of light to let her daughter die as she no longer has a head attached.

You're looking for The Asphyx from 1972. 

A Victorian scientist and his assistant discover the secret of death: everybody has a kind of personal "death spirit", the "asphyx"; when somebody is about to die, this "asphyx" comes in to claim his victim. If it can be caught at the right moment, immortality follows! The scientist succeeds in capturing his own asphyx, but when he starts experimenting on his daughter, he accidentally kills her. The assistant, his daughter's fiance, commits suicide; the scientist, wanting to die with them, tries to set his asphyx free again, but has forgotten the cipher code to the safe in which the spirit is kept. He is doomed to live forever...

Everything you mentioned is there (the car crash in the present, his daugther and the guillotine etc.) Here's the trailer:




@AJ It's because someone already asked about it recently... I'll try and find it.

That is the correct movie.  I am very happy to be able to watch it again after all these years. :D
